# ASP.NET MVC Pagination

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination

I have this project I'm working on, and I need to add paging to an audit history log. I'm not aware of if MVC comes standard with a way to add paging or if I would have to install a NuGet package. At any rate, here is the code I have so far for the audit log I need to implement paging for(I am using a repository pattern for this):

In the Interface I have this:

```
IEnumerable<AuditRecord> GetAuditRecords(Expression<Func<AuditRecord, bool>> filter, Func<IQueryable<AuditRecord>, IOrderedQueryable<AuditRecord>> orderBy = null, int pageIndex = 0, int pageSize = 20);
```

Then I have a UserHelper which has this:

```
public AuditInfo GetAuditInfo(SearchInfo searchInfo)
    {
        AuditInfo auditInfo = new AuditInfo();
        if (searchInfo != null)
        {
            List<AuditRecord> auditRecords =
                UserManager.GetAuditRecords(record => record.Username == searchInfo.UserName,
                                                records => records.OrderByDescending(record => record.Date), 0, 100);
            auditInfo.AuditRecords = auditRecords;
        }
        return auditInfo;
    }
```

Then in the controller:

```
public ActionResult AuditHistory(String username)
    {
        SearchInfo searchInfo = new SearchInfo { UserName = username };

        AuditInfo auditInfo = _userHelper.GetAuditInfo(searchInfo);

        return PartialView(auditInfo);
    }
```

And finally the view:

```
@if (Model != null && Model.AuditRecords != null && Model.AuditRecords.Count != 0)
{ 
<table required="False" border="0" class="data_std_results" id="tbl_std_documents">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <span class="resulttabletitle">Date</span>
            </th>
            <th>
                <span class="resulttabletitle">Action</span>
            </th>
            <th>
                <span class="resulttabletitle">Application</span>
            </th>
            <th>
                <span class="resulttabletitle">Modified by</span>
            </th>
            <th>
                <span class="resulttabletitle">Response</span>
            </th>
            <th>
                <span class="resulttabletitle"></span>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @{
int index = 0;
        }
        @foreach (var item in Model.AuditRecords)
        {                
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Date.ToString()
                </td>
                <td>@item.ActionKey
                </td>
                <td>@item.ApplicationName
                </td>
                <td>@item.Delegate
                </td>
                <td>@item.Response
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Comment))
                    {
                        <a href="@string.Format("#comment{0}", index)" class="comment">Details</a>
                        <div class="showNone">
                            <div id="@string.Format("comment{0}", index)" class="c_gen_lb_message">
                                <h3>@string.Format("{0} {1} for {2} at {3}", item.ActionKey, item.Response, item.ApplicationName, item.Date.ToString())</h3>
                                <h5>
                                    Comments:</h5>
                                @item.Comment
                                @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Reason))
                                {
                                    <h5>
                                        Reason:</h5>
                                    @item.Reason
                                }
                                <h5>
                                    Ip Address:</h5>
                                @item.IpAddress
                                @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Delegate))
                                { 
                                    <h5>
                                        Modified By:</h5>
                                    @item.Delegate
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
                    index = index + 1;
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="clearBoth">
</div>         
}
else
{
<p>
    no records found</p>
}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#tbl_std_documents').dataTable({
        "bFilter": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bSort": false,
        "bInfo": false
    });

    $("a.comment").fancybox({
        'type': 'inline',
        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
        'transitionOut': 'elastic',
        'hideOnContentClick': true,
        'speedIn': 600,
        'speedOut': 200,
        'overlayShow': false
    });

});
</script>
```

Any help or guidance on this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I've used [PagedList](http://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc) - it works very well with MVC. No need to write your own.

Comment: That's one option I was actually looking into.